# Docker container always in exited status

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ping

I am creating a virtual environment in docker for a University project.
I have several images that I am creating.
One of these needs to ping another docker container.
The problem is that it is always in exited status.
How can I do to not terminate my docker container?
Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:latest
#RUN apk add tcpdump
COPY . .
#CMD ["tcpdump" ,"-i" , "eth0" , "'icmp[icmptype] != icmp-echo'" ,"-w"," icmp_reply"]
CMD ["ping" , "172.19.1.3", ">", "ping.pcap"]
```

Here It is part of my docker-compose:

```
 ping_client:
  build: "../ClientPing_Amplification_Attack"
  image: "ping_client:latest"
  container_name: ping_client
  networks:
   rete_ping:   
    ipv4_address: 172.19.3.2
```

Here it is what I'm doing in my script:

```
docker-compose run -d ping_client
```

Do you have any suggestion for not exiting my docker container?
I think that my entry point should be a ping.
Why does it terminate?

Comment: had you checked the log of your container?

Comment: @Enix I'm trying to attach to my docker container. I'm always restarting the docker container.But It's always exiting, so I can't attach to the docker container. Do you know why?

Comment: no need to attach to the container, use `docker-compose logs ping_client` to check the log

Comment: @Enix the only output is: "attaching to"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace the `CMD ["ping" , "172.19.1.3", ">", "ping.pcap"]` from `ENTRYPOINT ping 172.19.1.3 > ping.pcap`

```
FROM alpine:latest
#RUN apk add tcpdump
COPY . .
#CMD ["tcpdump" ,"-i" , "eth0" , "'icmp[icmptype] != icmp-echo'" ,"-w"," icmp_reply"]
ENTRYPOINT ping 172.19.1.3 > ping.pcap
```

Answer (score 1):

First, show the log of instance

```
root@docker:~# docker logs [instance-id]
```

Second, if the instance start, try to connect with this a run the ping manually

```
root@docker:~# docker exec -it [instance-id] /bin/bash
```

Comment: I am using a network in my docker compose. If I try to start using exec there will be an error of "address already in use".

Comment: Start not, "IF start", try to enter of instance with this. Anyway, put this the output of log

Answer (score 1):

I basically tried to recreate your scenario with a stripped out version of your code and my answer would be to check your CMD command which in my case also exited with code 1.

```
ping_client exited with code 1
```

I changed your CMD command to execute bash, and there was no issue with the container:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk add --no-cache bash

CMD [ "bash" ]
```

Docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
 ping_client:
  build: .
  image: 'ping_client:latest'
  container_name: ping_client
```

Then `docker-compose run --rm ping_client` in which I able to use the terminal `bash-5.0#`.

So you're probably misusing ping and would need to run it manually inside the container to see if it actually works how you want it to.

Comment: I think you are right. But I'm trying to do a testbed and I have to reproduce this script several times (at least 30). It's quite boring for me to get inside manually and ping each time (I have to ping always the same static IP). Do you have any Idea for pinging the host, copying the .pcap file from the directory in docker to my host pc using a script?

Comment: You can still use your script but in any case you'll have to check that you're using ping correctly. I would try ping once manually if it works and then use that as a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

The `CMD` is in exec form meaning it is executed outside a shell. The `>` is a shell operator and it is not recognized as a valid option by `ping`.
Use the shell form to make it work:

```
CMD ping 172.19.1.3 > ping.pcap
```

[Difference between an Array and String Based CMD](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-63-difference-between-an-array-and-string-based-cmd)